# How to query rows that are not in a table?

Tags: mysql

First of all, I don't think my title is good, but I couldn't think of a better one. Please feel free to change it.

I have a table that keeps record of a pair of rows.

The following is a sample table structure.

**table History**

```
user_id    row_1   row_2
2            1       2 
2            1       3
```

**table Rows**

```
row_id
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I would like to query to get only a pair of rows that are not in the 'History' table.

so..I like to get the following result.

**row pairs:**

```
    1,4
    1,5
    1,6


    2,3
    2,4
    2,5
    2,6

and so on
```

Can I do it with one query?

**Just added:**

I just made a query that works, but I am not sure about the performance.

```
select r1.row_id, r2.row_id from rows as r1 cross join rows as r2
where r1.row_id!=r2.row_id and ( r1.row_id + r2.row_id) not in (select row_1 + row_2 from history)
order by r1.row_id desc
```

Would it be super slow?

Comment: does order matter? I.e. is `(1,2)` same as `(2,1)`?

Comment: In that case I'll have to edit my answer.

Comment: Another: you did not mention `(1, 1)` in your desired output, yet you have `(2, 2)`. Can you clarify why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN r1.row_id < r2.row_id THEN r1.row_id ELSE r2.row_id END AS row_id_1,
    CASE WHEN r1.row_id < r2.row_id THEN r2.row_id ELSE r1.row_id END AS row_id_2
FROM       Rows AS r1
INNER JOIN Rows AS r2 /* ON r1.row_id <> r2.row_id */
WHERE (r1.row_id, r2.row_id) NOT IN (
    SELECT row_1, row_2
    FROM history
    UNION
    SELECT row_2, row_1
    FROM history
)
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Returns:

```
1, 1
1, 4
1, 5
1, 6
2, 2
2, 3
2, 4
2, 5
2, 6
3, 3
3, 4
3, 5
3, 6
4, 4
4, 5
4, 6
5, 5
5, 6
6, 6
```

This query **will** be super slow.

Comment: // thank you for your reply. are there any other ways that I can make the query result faster? I don't mind if I need to change my table structure.

Comment: // I am actually create a photo challenge website. Rows table will hold list of photos. History table will hold the challenge result of photo x and photo y

Comment: @Moon: In that case you can try to _normalize_ the history table. Given the description, I am not sure what would be the best way to do this. It is worth that you post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this.  You haven't made the correlations clear between the fields but this should be easy to adapt.

```
select h.row_id r1, r.row_id r2
from rows h
cross join rows r
left join history h2 on h2.row_1=h.row_id and h2.row_2=r.row_id
where h2.row_1 is null
```

The CROSS JOIN produces all the possible combinations of row_id x row_id
THE LEFT JOIN attempts to find the combination in the history table
The WHERE clause picks out where the combination is not found

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi // I just tested the query and got the following result.

1,1
1,4
1,5
1,6

how do I get {2,2}, {2,3} and so on...?

Comment: @moon - updated based on your clarification. This is as fast as it will get.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: i think you got a couple of typos in your query. I also suggest that you add `OR (row_2 = row1)` in the `ON` clause.

Comment: @Salman thanks I caught a row_1->row_id. But why should the OR be in the ON clause?

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: As far as I understand from the sample data, the OP treats history records like `(999, 1, 2)` and `(999, 2, 1)` equally.

Comment: @Salman Maybe, maybe not: `"does order matter? I.e. is (1,2) same as (2,1)"` asking 2 questions at once does not an answer get `"no"`. (first or second?) If it is the first, then yes, adding `OR row_=row1` to the ON clause would be on point